# Android - error in dialog mode view

Tags: java, android, view, modal-dialog, label

I describe you my situation:

**Goal**:
I want activity that open in dialog mode, layout of that activity is only in half of screen in which I set Imageview, listview, button and textview.

**Problem**:
I see all Layout, also empty half, I also want remove the label on the top

this is a screenshot that describe my problem:

I wanna leave only the area in yellow rect and remove the other part

[image: I wanna leave only the area in yellow rect and remove the other part]

this is my code:

actvity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:id="@+id/b1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/centerShim5"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textview2"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/centerShim"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/centerShim" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/centerShim" />


    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:elevation="11dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/centerShim5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main2Activity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.macbookpro.provafragment">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

As suggested me, I tried with use of

```
android:layout_above="@+id/Button"
```

into activity_main2.xml but the result is the following [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcsvH.png)

Answer (score 0):

ActivityYou can define custom style in values/styles.xml like this:

```
<style name="Theme.ActivityDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And use it AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label=""
      android:theme="@style/Theme.ActivityDialog" />
```

The main issue is your view with id="centerShim" seems to be taking all the height. Add this line to center shim view 
android:layout_above="@+id/Button"

Comment: That could be a solution, but in this way I cover my problem by means of transparent layout, but I have always the same, because when I click  in the second half of the screen, the dialog activity don't close

Comment: have you tried setting width and height as "wrap_content" for the second activity?

Comment: Yes, the problem persist

Comment: Found out the issue.Your view with id="centerShim" seems to be taking all the height. Add this line to center shim view         android:layout_above="@+id/Button"

Comment: nope, I tried but don't work, I edited my ask with the screenshot of view

Answer (score 0):

In the image what You have attached is the screen, when your dialog is opened. In your dialog, the upper white portion is the Title bar of the dialog.
If you want to remove this title bar write this line just before setContentView() in your MAin2Activity.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

And your dialog is opened in the full screen mode. This is because you have set height of the parent layout to "match_parent" in activity_main2.xml.

Your activity_main2.xml should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/centerShim5"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textview2"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/centerShim"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/centerShim" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/centerShim"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/centerShim" />


    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:elevation="11dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/centerShim5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried with your code but I have the same problems.
Using `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` the title bar don't disappear, with your activity_main2.xml I have all white dialog with the same size like the one before

Comment: In that case You better try to open dialog using DialogFragment or custom Dialog Refer http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/ for Dialog fragment and https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/ for custom dialog in android

Comment: I tied both of example, but the problem is always the same, I can't understand why, I'm trying with different layout, all works, but when I use mine, don't.